# Uploading file with express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file with express-fileupload and am having no luck getting it to work. I can get the file (in this case an image) to 'upload' in the sense that I can get the console to show an image uploaded with the correct folder.

startup.js

```
router.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
    res.render('upload');
});

router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file 
  let startup_image = req.files.image;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server 
  startup_image.mv('/images' , function(err) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
  });
});
```

Then my html form is

```html
<form ref='uploadForm' 
      id='uploadForm' 
      action='/upload' 
      method='post' 
      encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
</form>
```

Comment: does it return an `err` for us to see?

Comment: Only gives this but I have had no luck figuring out what it means

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/images/josh.jpg'`

Comment: please check the update

Comment: please let me know if it worked

Answer (score 9):

You are pointing the directory where the file would go to, but you are not giving it a file name. I would say let the user decide the file name for the client side and add it to the path.

```html
<input name="userFileName" type="text">//userFilename Here</input>
```

```js
var myFILENAME = req.body.userFilename 
startup_image.mv('/images/'+myFILENAME+'.jpg', ..) //myFILENAME needs to be added here
```

Also please see Full Example in  [how to upload files with express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)

**UPDATE**

I found solution to your problem you need to add `__dirname` to this line which will let the program know your current directory to your `source` code.

```
startup_image.mv(__dirname + '/images' , function(err) {..
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is my source code, if you want you can try it with this.

my html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form ref='uploadForm' encType="multipart/form-data" class="" action="/upload" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="fileName" value=""><br>
      <input type="file" name="foo" value=""><br>
      <input type="submit" name="" value="upload!">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

my main source

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
//npm install ejs, express, express-fileupload

//middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(fileUpload());

app.get('/inputFile', function(req, res){
  res.render('inputt');
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
   var startup_image = req.files.foo;
   var fileName = req.body.fileName;
   // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
   startup_image.mv(__dirname + '/images/' + fileName + '.jpg' , function(err) {
     if(err){
       console.log(err);
     }else{
    console.log("uploaded");
}
   });
 });

app.listen(7777);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found that link which is what got me to where I am currently.I updated my code to have a filename that comes from a variable like you posted. Still getting the same error  `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/images/josh.jpg'`

Comment: @SeaitManageit please check the update, you need to put the full path

Comment: So my code now is `router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file 
  let startup_image = req.files.image;
 var fileName = req.body.fileName;
  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server 
  startup_image.mv(__dirname + '/images/' + fileName + '.jpg' , function(err) {
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
  });
});`
It shows the path correct (sorta, want it to go up a dir to save the image) but the actual image never shows up in my folder Page is stuck loading

Comment: I am using c9.io to host the test app while I build it, I am getting a Error 502 - Bad Gatewayafter the page loads for ~2 min it prints out an html file from c9.io

Comment: I have put my resource code, it works fine for me, please check it out @SeaitManageit

Comment: please let me know if the problems still persist with my code @SeaitManageit

Comment: I used your code and got the error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ubuntu/workspace/images/boat.jpg'` Only thing I changed code wise was the port number to the process.env.PORT and process.env.IP so that it would run on c9.io

Comment: var express = require("express");  <- second quote typo

Answer (score 2):

using async/await style

in your server file do this

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

 app.use(
  fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
    useTempFiles: true,
   // dir for windows PC
    tempFileDir: path.join(__dirname, './tmp'),
  }),
);
```

then in your controllers, do this

```
  const file = req.files.filename;
  await file.mv(file.name);

  if (!file || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).console.error('No files were uploaded.');
  }
```

Comment: You are a life saver. #Respect

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for non ejs and exporting modules solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form ref='uploadForm' encType="multipart/form-data" class="" action="/path/to/nodejs/upload/file" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="my_file"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="" value="upload">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now here is the NodeJS

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload({ safeFileNames: true, preserveExtension: true }))

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
    let the_file = req.files.my_file;

    the_file.mv('/path/to/html/uploads/up/' + the_file.name , function(err) {

        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.write(err);
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.log("uploaded");
            res.write("upload of file "+the_file.name+" complete");
            res.end();
        } 

   });

});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create folder **images**!

Answer (score 0):

```
//install path module 
const path = require('path');

 // remaining code

let startup_image = req.files.image;

startup_image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'/images',startup_image.name), function(error){
  //remaining code
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use complete sentences / code examples when giving a solution. It is very hard to understand your answer.

You will not only help the person you are answering, but it will help numerous other developers in the future who will have a similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

this way
file.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/images', filename)